# Why are the solutions of the $3\times 3$ system like that?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, proof-explanation, nonlinear-optimization, qcqp

Consider the problem:$$
\min \quad -x_1^2-4x_1x_2-x_2^2\\ \text{s.t.} \quad x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$$
The KKT system is given by\begin{align*}
x_1 (-1 + v) + 2 x_2 &= 0 \tag{1} ,\\ x_2 (-1 + v) + 2 x_1 &= 0 \tag{2},\\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 &= 1 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
The solutions according to the book are$$
(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\ v=3;\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\ v=3;\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\ v=-1,\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),\ v=-1,\\
$$
I tried to solved by hand: Substracting (1) and (2) I get $(x_1-x_2)(1+v)=0$. As $v$ cannot be zero (by the KKT condition) we have that $x_1=x_2$ if $v\neq -1$.

Thus I get the solutions:$$
(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right);\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right);\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right);\\
(x_1,x_2)=\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right);\\
$$
only asking $v\neq -1$.

Why the book ask $v=-1$ and $v=3$? Could someone explain please?

Comment: What an elegant way to write Alex, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need KKT conditions although the constraint is an equality?

Comment: @callculus Because the exercise says 'Consider the following problem: $\min ... s.t. ... $. a) Using KKT conditions, find the candidates to be solutions'

Comment: Also notice that I'm newbie in this, so I ususally take the long way instead of the short way by mistake of course.. :(

Comment: To me it seems that you just apply the lagrange multiplier method.

Comment: @callculus ah but if I remove the equation with equal sign the solution of the system would be $x_1=0=x_2$

Comment: what should I do then $?$

Comment: If you really have to use kkt maybe the idea is to split the equality constraint into two inequality constraints ($\leq, \geq$)

Comment: @callculus ok, so now the constraints would be $x_1^2+x_2^2\le 1$ and $-x_1^2-x_2^2\le -1$, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: @callculus and then the rest to do is to calculate $\nabla f+v_1\nabla g_1+v_2\nabla g_2=0$

Comment: I don´t think so. If you look at the method of KKT-condition you have several constraints and then you consider the  cases where the lagrange multipliers  are $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_1\geq 0, \lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2\geq 0$ and $\lambda_1\geq 0, \lambda_2\geq 0$ and

Comment: To get familiar with KKT you can browse at MSE for KKT or  kuhn tucker. One expample is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1077906/144421)

Comment: @callculus Is that KKT? I have a different definition of it. Many theorems that I have in my notes are like if $x$ satisfies $\nabla f+v_1\nabla g_1+v_2\nabla g_2=0$ then it's KKT. We are using Nonlinear programming book by Bazaraa

Comment: As I have already mentioned you can search here on MSE for KKT of kuhn tucker.

Comment: @callculus I checked KKT sufficient conditions. Consider the problem of the questions with s.t. $x_1^2+x_2^2-1\le0,-x_1^2-x_2^2+1\le0$. Let $\overline x$ be a feasible solution, $u_ig(\overline x)=0,u_i\ge0$ and $\nabla f(\overline x)+\sum u_i\nabla g_i(\overline x)=0$, then $\overline x$ is minimum local. I applied this conditions to the exercise and I get $u_1=0,u_2=1,u_2'=-3$ If I take the first two, then I have KKT conditions, and thus all the points that lie in the unit circle ae candidates to be solution? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your KKT system has a wrong sign, it must be
\begin{align*}
x_1 (-1 + v) \color{red}{-} 2 x_2 &= 0 \tag{1'} ,\\ x_2 (-1 + v) \color{red}{-} 2 x_1 &= 0. \tag{2'}
\end{align*}
However, the conclusion $(x_1-x_2)(1+v)=0$ from (1') minus (2') is correct.

You cannot get all four solutions "only asking $v\ne -1$" simply because if $v\ne-1$ then $x_1=x_2$, and it is only first two solutions that satisfy $x_1=x_2$. It means that when you study the case $v\ne-1$ you get first two solutions and $v=3$.

For a complete solution, you have to study the remaining case $v=-1$ as well. Set $v=-1$ into (1') and (2') to get $x_1+x_2=0$, i.e. $x_1=-x_2$, which gives you another two solutions from (3).

Comment: ? ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user441848 Something is unclear?

Comment: nop, I understand it finally :P

Answer (score 1):

Using **polar** coordinates,

$$\begin{aligned} x_1 &= \cos (\theta)\\ x_2 &= \sin (\theta)\end{aligned}$$

we obtain the **unconstrained** $1$-dimensional maximization problem in $\theta$

$$\text{maximize} \quad 1 + 2 \sin (2\theta)$$

Differentiating the objective and finding where the derivative vanishes, we obtain $\cos(2\theta) = 0$, whose solution set is

$$\left\{ \frac{\pi}{4} + k \frac{\pi}{2} : k \in \{0,1,2,3\} \right\}$$

Thus, in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$, the solution set is

$$\left\{ \pm \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right), \pm \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)\right\}$$

which is the same you obtained via other means.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo though the exercise asked using KKT

Answer (score 1):

$(x_1-x_2)^2\geq0$ gives $$x_1x_2\leq\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x_1=x_2$.

Thus,
$$-x_1^2-4x_1x_2-x_2^2=-1-4x_1x_2\geq-1-4\cdot\frac{1}{2}=-3.$$
The equality occurs for
$$(x_1,x_2)\in\left\{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right),\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)\right\}$$ only.

Comment: Why do you start with $(x_1-x_2)^2\geq0$ I cannot see the connection with the system.

Comment: It's explanation only. Because we need to delete $x_1x_2$.

Comment: ook.. And how does that implies $x_1x_2\leq\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}?$ I can see the equality (from the constraint condition) but I cannot see the inequality.

Comment: $x_1x_2\leq\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}$ it's $2x_1x_2\leq x_1^2+x_2^2$ or $x_1^2-2x_1x_2+x_2^2\geq0$ or $(x_1-x_2)^2\geq0.$ The equality occurs for $x_1-x_2=0$ or $x_1=x_2$.